# How do I know what radio firmware I'm running?

Tags: cyanogenmod, radio-firmware

I'm gearing up to mod my phone and reading the [Cyanogenmod Installation Support Line](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/278-installation-support-line-cyanogenmod-for-dreammagic/) which is helpful-ish right up until step 1.3, "1.3 Radio ...aka Which EBI am I?" They refer you to a post that makes almost no sense to me and which seems to be pretty damn important. I can't tell from it where I would look to see which EBI I am. In Recovery Flasher it shows my Phone Type as "EBI0/32B"

Looking at [the wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=How_to_determine_if_you_have_32A_or_32B) I find a whole page (I searched for "EBI0") I do see instructions for turning the phone off and holding down the back arrow while I power it back up. Here I see the following:

```
DREA100 PVT 32B
HBOOT-0.95.000
CPLD-4
RADIO-2.22.23.02

Sep 2 2008
```

I *think* this means I'm a 2x radio and thus can [safely install DangerSPL](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Dream%3aDangerSPL). Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, based on those posts you definitely have a 2.x radio that does not require the modified kernel.  Your radio version is also listed as supported on the DangerSPL page.  I think you're good to go, best of luck!